# Texture repeats even with GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE set

Tags: android, opengl-es

i'm trying to put a translucing texture on a face which uses points 1 to 4 (don't mind the numbers) on the following screenshot

[alt text http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/442/texturebug.png](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/442/texturebug.png)

Sadly as you can see the texture repeats herself in both dimensions, I tried to switch the TEXTURE_WRAP_S from REPEAT to CLAMP_to_EDGE but it doesn't change anything. Texture loading code is here :

```
gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture.get(4));
        gl.glActiveTexture(4);      
        gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                gl.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                gl.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexImage2D(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.GL_RGBA,
                shadowbmp.width, shadowbmp.height, 0,
                gl.GL_RGBA, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4,
                shadowbmp.buffer);
```

Texture coordinates are the following :

```
float shadow_bot_text[] = {                 
                    0.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.0f, 1.0f,
                    1.0f, 0.0f,
                    1.0f, 1.0f
                    };
```

Thanks

Comment: Does switching to glTexParameteri() help?

Comment: There is no glTexParameteri method, i tried with glTexParameterx but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the texture loader (png to buffer) itself not in the texture options
Sorry